# jdbc connection godaddy mysql java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, web-hosting

I have checked most of the comments for this problem and still couldn't work it out. I am using eclipse and writing the program with java, I have successfully established connections to my local SQL and everything was working

Now I am trying to connect to a DB in the goDaddy service

I am using the following format

```
private String conUrl = "jdbc:mysql://someIP:3306/DBname"; 
private String userName = "userName123";
private String pw ="userName123Password";

private static Set<Connection> conSet = new HashSet<Connection>();
public final int max_Con =5;
public static Object key = new Object();

private ConnectionPool() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
   //    java.sql.Driver test = DriverManager.getDriver(conUrl);
   //   System.out.println(test);


    for (int i = 0; i < max_Con; i++)
    {
        Connection con = 
        DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,userName,pw);    
        conSet.add(con);
    }
```

Where the username and its password is registered to the specific DB granted with all privileges.

I get an exception of the following

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'userName123'@'myIPadress.cablep.bezeqint.net' (using password: YES)

Did anyone encounter this problem?

I should mention that bezeqint.net is my internet supplier and a friend of mine did get a connection using a php application with the same DB.

Comment: i forgot to insert the imports:                                                                    
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

Comment: are you sure, you are able to connect to database using same username and password ?

Comment: import doesn't matter as your are getting error from your database.

Comment: you don't have a permission to connect

Comment: mySQL has few form to grant rights, for local acces simpler, for remote must add few parameters more.

Comment: since i wasnt sure about the previous username and password i created a new 1 and double checked it

Comment: is there a way to check if there is a connection attempt such as get available DB names within the host ip?